# C++ best way to copy all elements from vector into map / unordered_map

Tags: c++, set, unordered-map, unordered-set

Using C++, if I want to convert a `vector` into `set` or `unordered_set` container, it can be easily done by:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4};

    // pass
    unordered_set<int> uSet(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    // pass
    set<int> s(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    // fail
    unordered_map<int, size_t> uMap(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    // fail
    map<int, size_t> m(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    return 0;
}
```

However, the same technique doesn't work for `map` or `unordered_map` containers. I'm wondering if there is a better way to store all the elements from a vector into `map` / `unordered_map` container other than:

```
for (int ele : vec) {
    ++uMap[ele];
}
```

Also, which copy constructor from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set is called for the code below:

```
set<int> s(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

And why a similar copy constructor from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map is not available?

Comment: please one question per question

Comment: How is `map` supposed to guess the value type you want?

Comment: I believe the answers to your extraneous questions are (2) and (2). With that aside, we can focus on your main question: what do you expect `unordered_map<int, size_t> uMap(vec.begin(), vec.end());` to accomplish? This line says to construct a map from `int` to `size_t`, but you don't provide any `size_t`s. If that construction was to work, what do you expect to be the value of, let's say, `uMap[3]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your `set` construction.

> ```
> vector<int> vec {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4};
>
> set<int> s(vec.begin(), vec.end());
> ```

This succeeds because the `value_type` of your `set` is `int`. That's not just convenient terminology. A `std::set` defines a [member type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set#Member_types) called `value_type`, and I am saying that `std::set<int>::value_type` is `int`. Since dereferencing `vec.begin()` gives a value implicitly convertible to `int` (well, it *is* `int`), this construction succeeds.

Moving over to `map`, there is again a [member type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map#Member_types) called `value_type`. This time, though, `value_type` is not `int`, hence your proposed construction fails. The `value_type` of a `map` is a `pair` containing the key-value pair. That is, `std::map<int, size_t>::value_type` is `std::pair<const int, size_t>`. Since there is no known conversion from `int` to any flavor of `std::pair`, your proposed construction fails.

If you had instead worked from a `vector` of `pair`s, your construction could succeed.

```
vector<pair<const int, size_t>> vecp { {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 4} };

map<int, size_t> m(vecp.begin(), vecp.end());
```

This results in `m[1] == 2`, `m[2] == 3`, `m[3] == 3`, and `m[4] == 4`. The extra `{4,4}` is dropped because this is a `map`, not a `multimap`. (It is unspecified whether the first or second `{4,4}` is dropped, but whichever is dropped is the extra one.)

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT. So can we conclude that to count elements' frequency from a vector using `unordered_map` or `map` is to use the `for`-loop? Sometimes I just want to explore fancy ways...

Answer (score 1):

A map entry has two "values", while a vector has only one.
If you want to insert vector elements into a map, you need to decide which
values are going to be the keys and which are going to be the values.
The way of doing that is using a vector of pairs (vector < pair < K , V > >), which can be used to initialize a map as you had already done before.